# How may I prove this integral inequality?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Prove the following inequality:

$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\le\int_{0}^{1}  \left({\log(\csc(x))}\right)^{1/3} dx$$

What should i start with? (it's not a homework but a hobby related activity)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $\sqrt{\pi}/2=\Gamma(3/2)$.

For $0<x\le 1$ we have $\csc(x)>1/x$ so
$$
\int_0^1 (\log(\csc(x)))^{1/3}~dx > \int_0^1(-\log(x))^{1/3}~dx
$$
Substitute $y=-\log(x)$ to get
$$
\int_0^1(-\log(x))^{1/3}~dx = \int_0^\infty y^{1/3}e^{-y}~dy=\Gamma(4/3)
$$
So your inequality follows from $\Gamma(4/3)>\Gamma(3/2)$. Unfortunately $\Gamma(4/3)$ does not have a simple expression, so I don't yet see a way to show this last step except by evaluating it numerically.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I completed the proof by editing your post rather than saying it in the comments. It would have been too long and belongs as part of the answer anyway.

Comment: @Zander: thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Ragib I don't mind the edit, but I don't think it's correct. $\Gamma(x)$ has its minimum at $x=1.46\ldots<3/2$, e.g. $\Gamma(3/2)-\Gamma(1.45)>0.0005$. Your error is that $\psi(3/2)=\psi(1/2)+2>0$.

Comment: @Zander Sorry about that. I just checked now that $\Gamma(4/3)-\Gamma(3/2) \approx 0.007$, which I believe is too close to $0$ to show it is positive without getting things getting messy. I don't think we can avoid it.

Comment: @Zander: I thought that if $\Gamma'(3/2)\le0$, then since $\Gamma$ is log-convex, we would have $\Gamma'(x)\le0$ for all $x\le3/2$. However,
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma'(3/2)/\Gamma(3/2)
&=\mathrm{H}(1/2)-\gamma\\
&=H(-1/2)+2-\gamma\\
&=2-\gamma-2\log(2)\\
&\stackrel{.}{=}0.036489973978576520559
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma'(4/3)/\Gamma(4/3)
&=\mathrm{H}(1/3)-\gamma\\
&=H(-2/3)+3-\gamma\\
&=3-\gamma-\frac12\left(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}+3\log(3)\right)\\
&\stackrel{.}{=}-0.13203378002080632300
\end{align}
$$
It looks as if computation is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Proving such a thing with simple "analytic" inequalities seems hopeless, due to the combination of $\log$, $\csc$ and exponentiation by $1/3$- the integrand just seems too ugly for any simple "trick" to work. So we have to get our hands dirty.

Calculating the derivative gives $\displaystyle \frac{-\cot x}{3 (\log (\csc(x)))^{2/3}}$ and since for $x\in [0,1]$ $\cot x \geq 0$ and $\csc (x) \geq 1$ we see the derivative is always $\leq 0$, i.e the function is decreasing. Thus taking right handed Riemann sums underestimates the integral.

$$\int^1_0 \sqrt[3]{ \log(\csc (x))} dx > \frac{1}{20}\sum_{k=1} \sqrt[3]{ \log \left(\csc \left(\frac{k}{20}\right)\right)} = 0.915... $$

And since $\pi < 3.24 = 1.8^2$, we have $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} < 0.9$ so the desired inequality is reached.

Comment: thank you for your solution. However, my aim is to solve it elegantly without using calculator.